# build.gradle Resolve circular without refactor

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a legacy project which uses gradle. It have "main" build.gradle script, ":api" and ":server" parts, where subproject ":server" depends on ":api" subproject.
But now I need to enable circular dependency on these subprojects. Yeah, I know that it is bad idea, but honestly I have no idea why guy who works with it before me had divided this project on these subprojects. Anyway, I can't refactor project here.
So, how I can "enable" circularity in build scripts?

Comment: You can't. Stick with the design, or use a single project.

Comment: ok. but is there a fast way to "concat" projects?